# Passing Text & Value in ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, listitem

I've tried to make my combobox pass a text and then a value. But i can't get the value.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("abc", 23));
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("def", 56));
```

Then I try get the value when i've selected any of these in the Combobox

```
 string text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
 string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

 this.label5.Text = text + " with value: " + value;
```

This results in a crash with following error code:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

If I just use the "text" variable, everything is fine.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I know that I get null and that will help me not crash, but why is the value not passed on to / from the ComboBox? Thanks in advanced

**SOLUTION:**
This is how I managed to solve it.

```
        var source = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        source.Add("College", 100);
        source.Add("T-shirt", 54);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = source.ToList();
        DropDownList1.DisplayMember = "Key";
        DropDownList1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

And then

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = DropDownList1.Text;
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        //[etc…]

        this.label5.Text = "Cloth:" + selectedItem + " costs " + value;
    }
```

Hope this can help anyone.

Thanks all for help!

Comment: could you check if selected value is being filled?

Comment: How am I suppose to do this?

Comment: Add a break point after it should be filled and then hover your mouse over the var.

Comment: that is why you're getting the error you need to add an is null check ill add an answer

Comment: Yes, any suggestion why no value is passed from/to the ComboBox?

Comment: If the question is answered, you should put the answer as an answer and accept it. If others answered it, you should mark their answer as correct. As it is, this question still appears unanswered in searches.

Comment: Sorry, first post for me. None of the answers below did give me the right answer. How can I close it with my own answer? I can't post an answer until 8 hours...

Comment: Please post an answer of your own when you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this quite a long ago. But I think you need to use it like this:

```
var selectedItem = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
if (selectedItem != null)
{
    string text = selectedItem.Text;
    string value = selectedItem.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't said which line the exception is thrown on, so it's a bit of a shot in the dark. However:

```
string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

`DropDownList1.SelectedValue` might be null, in which case trying to call ToString() on it would cause a NullReferenceException. Try:

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == null)
   return;

var value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
this.label5.Text = String.Format("{0} with value: {1}", text, value);
//[etc…]
```

**Update**:

Assuming that your combobox isn't databound since you are adding items in memory, you need to set the default selected value as well.  You would need to find the object's index in the `Items` collection on your form and then set the `SelectedIndex` property to the appropriate index.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("abc", 23));
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("def", 56));
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf("abc");
```

Keep in mind that the `IndexOf` function may throw an `ArgumentException` if the item is not in the collection.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the SelectedValue is null. Why is it?

Comment: A possible cause might be that you are using a `DropDownStyle` of `DropDown` and typing into the ComboBox. I'm assuming because the value entered is no longer one of the items in the `ComboBox`.
If this is the case, set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`, assuming the user has to pick an existing value.

Comment: Have you set the `DataSource` property? ComboBox has to have `DataSource`. Link data though `DropDownList1.DataSource`

Comment: Don't think i'll need this because I use Window Application. But when I try I get this:
Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataTextField' and no extension method 'DataTextField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\eperthu\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 48 27 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: @user3668242 I have updated my answer with more info.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind this data before you use it, try it:

myDropdown.DataBind()

Just after adding your items and it may solve it, I think you can find tons and tons of tutorials about it, just Google it

Comment: You don't need to DataBind if you add items directly.

Comment: Hi,
I think you are right, i need the DataBind. But when I use it i get error:
Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataTextField' and no extension method 'DataTextField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 48 27 WindowsFormsApplication1

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check whether your combobox is selected or not 

 if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
       string text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
       string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
       this.label5.Text = text + " with value: " + value;
    }
    else
    {
    // message to select option
    }
```

Please note- We have ComboBox in Windows Application and Dropdownlist in Asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check to check of i = null like this:

```
        label1.text = DropDownList1.selectedItem.Value != null ? DropDownList1.selectedItem.Text + " with value: " + DropDownList1.selectedItem.Value : label1.text;
```

This should do the trick it checks if i != null;

you're getting the error because you cant an empty variable with +

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind this data before you use it, try it:

myDropdown.DataBind()

Just after adding your items and it may solve it, I think you can find tons and tons of tutorials about it, just Google it

I think there may be none item selected, and you're calling .ToString()  in a null value, I cant figure it out without more context, how are you trying to get the selected value?

Comment: Hi,
I think you are right, i need the DataBind. But when I use it i get error:
Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataTextField' and no extension method 'DataTextField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 48 27 WindowsFormsApplication1

Any idea?

Comment: Talking to me? I've added the solution in my question.